# What does the @ sign and the number next to it mean in ls -l display?

Tags: macos, mac, unix

I got the following output when I apply `ls -l` command in my Mac OS X Mavericks for an image file:

[image]

I understand what does `-rw-r--r--` mean. But what does the @ sign and the number next to it mean? Is similar feature available in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "@" means that the file has extended attributes.  You can see them with the `xattr` command.  The "1" is the number of links to that file.  In most cases, for normal files, this will be "1".  For directories, it is the number of files/subdirs + 2 (the two actually represents the directory itself, and the parent directory).